# Ant create android project

Tags: android, ant, project

I know that Ant is a build tool. We write script (steps while releasing android project) to build an android project and create a signed apk. Thats is one of the uses of Ant. 
 But I want a method/script to create a new project in Android and I also want to build it so that an apk file can be created through that method/script. Is it possible through Ant?
i.e. Ant script create a new project with a package name and activity name provided in the script, build it and create an apk file ready to be loaded in the emulator or device.
Is there any solution(method/script) to the above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this through ant via a command line call to 'android create project' which will in turn generate all the ant scripts.

Comment: But that would only create a default project with build.xml(ant build file). This command does not even create drawable folder in res folder. It also creates an empty bin folder.<br/> But how a script can be created and running it creates the above empty android project and genrates an apk file?

Comment: you can create the drawable folder with ant commands.  why does the empty bin folder matter?

Comment: I am new to Ant. Please provide me link. My problem : An ant script while executing it creates an android project and builds the same project's apk file. Another question is it possible to create a project from another project(copy project with similar folder structure heirarchy)?

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/ for the list of everything

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html to make a directory

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything built in for copying a project.  It wouldn't be too hard to create an ant script to do that though...